# Trying to blink (2) LEDs using RPi.GPIO module

Tags: rpi.gpio

I'm a noobie with Python3 and am having problems getting (2) LEDs to blink. The threads run one after the other and not concurrently.

```py
'''
    Python3 - gpio_test_02
            - use threads to blink leds from GPIO pins
'''
import threading
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Set GPIO mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
print("GPIO mode: BCM {}".format(GPIO.getmode()))

# Class definition
class Blink_LED(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, pin, counter, delay, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.pin     = pin
        self.counter = counter
        self.delay   = delay
        self.name    = name
        print("New class - {} {} {} {}".format(self.name, self.pin, self.counter, self.delay))

    def run(self):
        try:
            GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.OUT)
            i = 0
            while i <= self.counter:
                print(i, "", self.pin)
                GPIO.output(self.pin, GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                GPIO.output(self.pin, GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                i += 1
        except:
            RuntimeWarning
# end class Blink_LED

def main():
    11# Run the threads
    T1 = Blink_LED(19, 10, 0.25, "T1")
    T2 = Blink_LED(13, 10, 0.25, "T2")

    T1.run()
    T2.run()

    T1.join()
    T2.join(T1)

    # cleaning up all GPIO
    GPIO.cleanup()
# end mIn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the following modifications.

1. After the line `print("New class - {} {} {} {}".format(self.name, self.pin, self.counter, self.delay))` add the line `self.start()`.
2. Comment out the `T1.run()` and `T2.run()` lines.
3. Change `T2.join(T1)` to `T2.join()`.

Did you modify the example?